# Vagrant - how to start Apache after mounts are done

Tags: linux, apache, vagrant

How can I setup vagrant in a way, that on guest machine, Apache is started (or any bash command is executed) after vagrant does mount.

Reason is that in a mount I have essential modules which I need for apache.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem a couple of days ago and as I spend some time investigating I decided to write a blog post after solving it: http://razius.com/articles/launching-services-after-vagrant-mount

Comment: The (very useful) posted article is now at http://razius.com/articles/launching-services-after-vagrant-mount/

Comment: we shouldn't be posting links to blogs but posting actual answers